# Unable to resolve module, react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native, navigation, stack

[image]

I'm not understanding what this error means

Is there something I need to install?

Comment: I had similar issues with my project.
I was using stack navigator and even after installing everything I thought I needed it wasnt working. 
If you're using the same type of navigation install - npm i react-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it via npm using

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```